# CombineLatest first event not firing

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to know when my application goes offline and comes back online. I have the following events registered in `rxjs`:

```
const online = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'online');
const offline = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'offline');

const source = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(online, offline).map(() => navigator.onLine);

source.subscribe(result => {
  console.log('I\'m online: ' + (result ? 'jup' : 'nope'));
});
```

But, the first time I go offline the event isn't triggered allthough if I add the regular `addEventListener` events I see they're getting triggered fine:

```
window.addEventListener('online', () => console.log('online triggered'));
window.addEventListener('offline', () => console.log('offline triggered'));
```

Take a look at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zegidegiba/edit?js,console) as example, switch of your netwerk via devtools and you'll see the first time it won't log `I'm online: ...`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `combineLatest` operator requires all source Observables to emit at least one value.

For you this means you should initialize each stream and then just listen to changes:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    online.startWith(null),
    offline.startWith(null),
  )
  .skip(1)
  .map(() => navigator.onLine)
```

Maybe you don't even need to use the `skip(1)` if you want to know the initial state of `navigator.onLine`.

Comment: Thanks, indeed `skip` isn't necessary in my case.

Comment: Thank you @martin!

Comment: this is what is needed, thank you